Rust - Failed to Resolve Import
I've read the section in the Rust Book on importing crates but I am still missing something.
I have a project structure like:
hello_world
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
└── src
    ├── auth
    │   └── mssql.rs
    ├── auth.rs
    ├── pipeline.rs
    └── main.rs


my code looks like:
main.rs
pub mod pipeline;

use crate::pipeline::Pipeline;
fn main()  {
    let p = Pipeline {credentials: "my_user".to_string()};
}

pipeline.rs
use crate::auth::mssql; // error here

pub struct Pipeline {
    pub credentials: String,
}

impl Pipeline {
    pub fn get_auth() {
        mssql::authenticate();
    }
}

auth.rs
pub mod mssql;

mssql.rs
pub fn authenticate() {
    println("authenticated");
}

I receive the following error:
 use auth::mssql;
  |     ^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `auth`

I've looked at many examples of similar issues online but cannot wrap my head around why I am getting this error.
If I understand correctly based on the book example here, this should work.
Isn't use crate::auth::mssql supposed to look in auth.rs and find the included mssql.rs via pub mod mssql?

You didn't put mod auth in main.rs.

@ChayimFriedman so main has to use mod auth for all downstream packages even if it isn't using the auth module in main.rs? Is there a more sensible way to do this?

Downstream modules, not packages, but yes. Each module must have a declaration, and conventionally it is placed in the file one level above, even if it's not used there.

@ChayimFriedman I see. A little interesting. I was wondering if I could just use a lib.rs to include everything downstream and somehow get that into main for this purpose. Is my overall process and structure above "unconventional" in any way?

You can have a library and binary in the same package, (aka lib.rs and main.rs), and the binary will be able to use all the exported functions of the library (but not the private). It is a common approach, but not necessary. I don't find your approach to be unconventional.
